# Pandas - resample on non-datetime

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
n    Date        Area    Rank

12  2007-03-02  Other   4.276250
24  2007-03-02  Other   4.512632
3   2007-03-02  Other   3.513571
36  2007-03-02  Other   4.514000
48  2007-03-02  Other   4.55000
```

I want to resample for values between the `n` interval, to ultimately interpolate the `rank` field once I have those values.  If `n` were a datetime or similar object, I could just resample.  How would I do that but with a float or int?

Output should be something like this (dummy numbers for Rank, just an example)

```
n    Date        Area    Rank

3   2007-03-02  Other   3.513571
4   2007-03-02  Other   3.513675
5   2007-03-02  Other   3.524819
6   2007-03-02  Other   3.613427
7   2007-03-02  Other   3.685635
....
....
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to interpolate `Rank` on integer-valued intervals of `n`?  Meaning, for `n=3`, `Rank` is `Rank[n=12]` + 1/12 the value between `n=12` and `n=24`?

Comment: Yes - sorry for the lack of clarity - late in the day and I'm about spent :)  I know what I want to do and the logic part is simple, just having some issues converting that logic to pandas / increasing the sampling.

Comment: i think i figured it out... `reindex` over the range of `n` I want, and then interpolate the NaN's.

Comment: Does date change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = (df.set_index('n')
        .reindex(range(df.n.min(), df.n.max()))
        .interpolate()
        .reset_index())
df[['Date','Area']] = df[['Date','Area']].ffill()
```

Output:

```
     n        Date   Area      Rank
0    3  2007-03-02  Other  3.513571
1    4  2007-03-02  Other  3.598313
2    5  2007-03-02  Other  3.683055
3    6  2007-03-02  Other  3.767797
4    7  2007-03-02  Other  3.852539
5    8  2007-03-02  Other  3.937282
6    9  2007-03-02  Other  4.022024
7   10  2007-03-02  Other  4.106766
8   11  2007-03-02  Other  4.191508
9   12  2007-03-02  Other  4.276250
10  13  2007-03-02  Other  4.295948
11  14  2007-03-02  Other  4.315647
                                ...
```

There may be a way to interpolate using different methods, based on column type - then you wouldn't need the separate `ffill()` for the non-`float` columns.  I played around with `apply()` a bit, but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Yeah, this is pretty much what I ended up going with once I discovered reindex. Marking as approved for your efforts and future readers